# How to split an ansible local_action in multiple lines

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a local_action the I would like to split in multiple lines.

```
  - name: Find geographical region of this server
    local_action: uri url=http://locator/studio/{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address}} method=GET return_content=yes register=locator_output
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The task is defined using `shorthand syntax`. The same result could be achieved by using the regular syntax and `delegate_to` parameter, like this:

```
- name: Find geographical region of this server
  uri:
    url: http://locator/studio/{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address}}
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
  register: locator_output
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: I like this syntax more.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use `module` parameter with the original action name:

```
  - name: Find geographical region of this server
    local_action:
      module: uri
      url: http://locator/studio/{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address}}
      method: GET
      return_content: yes
    register: locator_output
```